# Handel more than one value returned

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
Update company set comp_wholesale=(select comp_wholesale from company    
                                    where comp_companyID=100 and comp_isparent='Y' ) 
where comp_parentcompany=1200
```

I need to execute this and update all which works fine but how can I do that with whole table i mean without  explicitly defining ID(1200 and 100). I want it to work for all records.  Any procedure code to function which can do this

When I try in procedure I get the error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

This is not permitted when the subquery follows, but to make it generic to work with whole table it has to return more than one value . How this can be done?

Comment: Could you tell us how comp_parentCompany relates to comp_companyID?

Comment: compID    parentID     isPArent     comp_wholesale 
 1               Null              yes             123.14
 2               1                 Null                null 
 3               1                 Null                null 
 4                Null            Null                11.2

hope this will help, if yo uneed more information let meknow.

Comment: i sent you in a table format, let me know if you did not get in table format

Comment: Why do you have 1200 and 100 in your example? Why are they not the same? Do you want to copy the `comp_wholesale` from some other company than the parent?

Comment: company 100 is a parent company which has a child company. ID for child company is 1200 .  if isParent field is 'Y' that mean this company is parent and has child company too. Child company has column parentID which holds id of parent .   in short all the Parent companies has isParent ='Y' and all the child company has ParentID field set to companyID of their parent.  What I need to do is to update comp_wholesale of all the child companies to the values of comp_wholesale of their Parent company   . let me if you need more information  thanks

Comment: In that case the `where` clause of your example should read either `where comp_parentcompany=100`  or `where comp_companyID=1200`.

Comment: Can more than one row in  `company` have the same `comp_companyID`?

Comment: no company ID is unique , no two companies can have same companyID

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to refer to the table `company` twice in the same SQL. Use alias names (in this case I have chosen `c1`and `c2`) so that the query optimiser knows which one you are referring to:

```
Update company c1 
inner join company c2 
   on c2.comp_companyID=c1.comp_parentcompany 
set c1.comp_wholesale=c2.comp_wholesale 
where c1.comp_parentcompany is not null
```

This will update all companies that have a parent.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7b89/1

Comment: sorry i think i forget to mention both parent and child  are held in same table name company there are no two separate tables for them.

Comment: @DevSrb It is pretty obvious that they are both in the same table but I'm a bit confused by your shifting terminology. I assume that `ParentID` and `comp_parentcompany` is the same field?

Comment: yes ParentID and comp_parent company is same , sorry for that .  i got an error . Incorrect syntax near 'c1'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: I had forgotten the `c2` qualifier in two places. Should work now.

Comment: still gives error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'c1'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Seems mysql doesn't support that way of doing it (Oracle does). I've rewritten it as a `join` so that it works in mysql.

Comment: can you please send me latest  rewritten query that works in mySql

Comment: thanks but i get this error in mysql Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'c1'.    but in works fine in SqlFiddle. don't know why

Comment: fields are right.. just to let you know when I try this --- update Company  set comp_name='ABc' where comp_companyid=18 it works fine but this ---- update Company  c1 set c1.comp_name='ABc' where c1.comp_companyid=18   gives syntax error near  c1 is it something to do with mysql version or something

Comment: but again   select c1.comp_name from company c1 where c1.comp_companyid=18 
   works fine ..  so its issue with alias in update

Comment: Do you have an old version of mysql? Back in 2011 there was problems such as this: http://verysimple.com/2011/03/30/mysql-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/

Comment: You could try adding `AS`: `Update company AS c1 
inner join company AS c2 ...` Shouldn't make a difference, but I don't have any other ideas..

Comment: hello, thanskf ro helop but i am still facing issue and stuck at same point . i was trying to do by procedure but got errors again .. can let me know if its possible in procedure.  there is pseudo code.                                                         array =(select comp_companyID from company where comp_deleted is null and comp_isparent='Y' )
for (i=1 to array.count;i++)
{
update comp_ststu='Avtive' where comp_companyID=array[i]

}
can i use array in procedure and look each id and then update.